# :after tag that expands to fill remaining width of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sass

I have a a h1 element with an :after tag that needs to dynamically expand to fill the remaining width of the containing div. Basically it needs to have a width of calc(*h1_width* - 100%), where the h1 width isn't set or hardcoded. Can this be done via SASS or will I need to use a JS option to manipulate the DOM? [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wpmqLfp6/1/).

HTML

```
<div class="text-box__wrap">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
</div>
```

CSS

```
  .text-box__wrap {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 2em auto 0;
    padding: 0 20px;
  }

  .text-box__wrap h1 {
    margin-bottom: 4%;
    letter-spacing: 1.5px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    &:after {
      display: inline-block;
      /* Needs to be dynamic based on difference of h1 width and remaining div width */
      width: 50px;
      height: 1px;
      margin-left: 10px;
      content: "";
      vertical-align: 30%;
      background-color: black;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `display:flex` on the `h1` to make the `:after` take the remaining space:

```css
.text-box__wrap {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 2em auto 0;
  padding: 0 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.text-box__wrap h1 {
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.text-box__wrap h1:after {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1px;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  margin-left: 10px;
  content: "";
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-box__wrap">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
</div>
```